# An estimation method/algorithm for estimating the value of a specific parameter in a convex function

Tags: estimation, computational-statistics, identifiability, point-estimation, iteration-methods

I am looking for an estimation/iteration process to estimate the value of a specific unobserved parameter of a convex function that fits the observed data of the other variables closely. Specifically, in the following equation b, v, r and n are observed through an experimental procedure and I would like to estimate the value of α that fits the data most closely. Note that this equation was derived from an optimization problem.

\begin{align}
      b &= v-\frac{av^\frac{n+a-1}{a}-ar^\frac{n+a-1}{a}}{(n+a-1)v^\frac{n-1}{a}} 
\end{align}

Comment: Is $a$ the same thing as $\alpha$?

Comment: Also, you tagged this post with `identifiability`. Do you believe some of the parameters are not identifiable? I don't see any identifiability issues but I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes, there are the same thing! Sorry for the confusion!
I do believe that there is point identification, maybe wrongly I tagged the post with identifiability. Actually, I am searching for a method to estimate it.

Comment: Can you subtract $b$ from both sides of the equation then find where the equation is 0?

Comment: Is there an error term in your equation? E.g. $b = f(a; b, v, r, n) + \epsilon$

Comment: I cannot solve for the parameter α. I am searching for the value of the unobserved parameter α that fits closely the data on the observed parameters of b, v, r and n based on this equation.

Comment: No, there is not. This equation was derived from an optimization problem (first order condition) and solved for b.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133990/discussion-between-koula-and-eli).